# Google does not correctly merge microdata and json+ld in the same page using same URI id

Tags: schema.org, microdata, json-ld, structured-data

I have a product page with "microdata" and "json+ld" codes. Both of the codes refers to the same @id URI object (http://www.example.org/product#this) so I would expect to "mix/merge" both properties, but instead structured data testing tool shows 2 "individual" products so....

1- Does Google support using two syntax in the same page?
2- Is this well implemented? Can I refer two codes to the same object using itemId for microdata and @id for json+ld?
3- Can this damage my page in terms of structure data indexing?

thanks

You can check it out using this code in [test tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemid="http://www.example.org/product#this">
    <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.org/product">
    <div itemprop="name"><strong>Product Name</strong></div></a>
    <div itemprop="description">Product Description</div>
    <div itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">Product Brand</span></div>
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">        <span itemprop="price">100</span><link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition" /> New</div>
</div>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@id": "http://www.example.org/product#this",
  "name": "Product Name",
  "@type": "Product",
  "image": "http://www.example.com/anvil_executive.jpg",
  "mpn": "925872",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "ACME"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "USD",
    "price": "119.99",
    "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock"
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool doesn’t support this for different syntaxes, as it seems to work if using the same syntax. But as they still display the URIs correctly (`http://www.example.org/product#this` in both cases), you could argue that it’s just the tool’s interface that doesn’t merge them.
However, as far as I know Google does not document to support these subject URIs anyway (but this doesn’t necessarily mean that they don’t support it), so it might not matter for them.

Your example works fine if using http://linter.structured-data.org/: it creates *one* item with both brands and both offers.

Comment: Thanks @unor, you are correct and it seems that with http://linter.structured-data.org/ it works...

Comment: Google doesn't support merging two different syntaxes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59747826/565110

Answer (score 3):

While technically it is feasible to merge data coming from two different syntaxes (read microdata and json-ld) and the Structured Data Linter confirms so, Google **does not** support it, which means properties won't be merged (and won't satisfy Rich Snippets' requirements).

We have a final confirmation by several actors in the SEO World, including [Dan Brickley](https://twitter.com/danbri) and [Jarno van Driel](https://twitter.com/JarnoVanDriel).

> in general you can use both syntaxes side by side, but **you won't get
>   the fine-grained merging of triples by ID** that a pure RDF application
>   might expect (Dan Brickley on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/danbri/status/1217060600305651718), Jan 14th, 2020, *bold mine*)

--

> I think @danbri already was pretty clear. Highly doubt you'll get a
>   different answer from other Googlers. (Jarno van Driel on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JarnoVanDriel/status/1217136761824038912), Jan 14th, 2020)

The proposed solution so far is to parse the microdata and publish it as JSON-LD.