# ID of html element apparently conflicts with Schema.org data

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have a `<div>` element with download description. That also contains Schema.org structured data used for google indexing. See this sample:

```
<div id="about-download" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication">
  You're about to download latest stable release of <span itemprop="name">My Program</span>.
  <br />
  My Program currently only works on <span itemprop="operatingSystem">Windows</span>
  <link itemprop="applicationCategory" href="http://schema.org/GameApplication"/>
</div>
```

Now google seems to misinterpret the `id="about-download"` into something else:

[image: image description]

This must be dealt with, it seems to point to invalid URL. The path to download page is just `http://xxxx.github.io/xxxxxxx/download/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Google Testing Tool use the "id" attribute to generate a URL for the Microdata item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491507/why-does-google-testing-tool-use-the-id-attribute-to-generate-a-url-for-the-mi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google does not correctly merge microdata and json+ld in the same page using same URI id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756091/google-does-not-correctly-merge-microdata-and-jsonld-in-the-same-page-using-sam)