# Microdata and Json-ld

Tags: microdata, json-ld, structured-data, google-search-console

I have an e-commerce website , so to markup my products i am using schema.org vocabulary.

However, previously i used microdata and google seo recognised it as a structured data and i can see my items in the structured data column.

[image]
[image]

But, when i click the Rich cards feature, it doesn't show up any markup for my products.

[image]

So what i did was i used `json-ld` as well.Now, if i were to go to `https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool` and fetch my url there, i can see `26` products instead of `13`.

I get it ,i used both of them hence twice the no of products.

What i wanted to know was , why am i not be able to see rich cards and if i mix both of them , does that hinder google search results?

Comment: Your question post should only contain one primary question, but you have two (1. rich cards, 2. mixing Microdata and JSON-LD). For 2., we already have the question [*JSON-LD and Microdata on the same page?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41034582/1591669).

Comment: Thank you @unor .How about the rich cards problem/.?

Comment: I don’t know Google’s tools, so I’m not sure. Maybe your markup doesn’t qualify for rich cards (as Google supports only a small subset of Schema.org)? If you want to make your question about this, you should include minimal markup in your question post which should lead to an rich result.