# Structured data: mixing JSON with Microdata causes errors

Tags: schema.org, microdata, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm trying to mark up an article with structured data. For this particular article I've found it a lot cleaner and simpler to use JSON rather than Microdata. In Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) this script works fine with no errors:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Article",
      "mainEntityOfPage": {
         "@type": "WebPage",
         "@id": "https://my_website/my_article.php"
      },
      "author": "My name",
      "name": "My article",
      "headline": "My article",
      "datePublished": "2017-06-10",
      "dateModified": "2017-07-23",
      "image":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://my_website/images/my_logo.png","height":768, "width":782},
      "publisher" : {
          "@type": "Organization", 
          "name": "My site name",
          "logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://my_website/images/my_banner.png","height":60, "width":600}
        }
    }
```

However, the article body is very long so I don't want to put that in the script via articleBody. Instead I've used Microdata:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" class="col-md-8">
     <div itemprop="articleBody" class="card">
          <!-- Rest of my HTML -->
```

As soon as I do this the testing tool gives an error for every single item in my JSON, saying those fields are required.

Is there a way to do this without duplicating 3,000 lines of content into the JSON script articleBody?

Comment: Why the heck was this rated down? It's a clear question with a MCVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating two `Article` items. The errors are reported for the item created with Microdata, not for the item created with JSON-LD.

Theoretically, the solution would be to convey that the two `Article` items describe the *same* article, not two different articles. This can be done by [giving them the same URI as ID](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633): with `@id` in JSON-LD, with `itemid` in Microdata ([example with JSON-LD and Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036600/1591669)).

However, currently Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool [doesn’t seem to support this for mixed syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33778601/1591669) (apart from [curious exceptions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90525/17633)). When the same syntax is used, it "merges" all items with the same ID.

There doesn’t seem to be another option.

If you only care about [Google’s Article rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles), note that the `articleBody` property doesn’t seem to be supported. So you could either omit the Microdata `Article` item, or you could wait to see if Google manages to show the rich result for your page (from your JSON-LD item) despite having another "incomplete" Microdata item on the page.

Comment: Thanks. So theoretically I'd use itemid="#this", or rather the URL for the page to denote the same thing as I've given in the JSON with the @type, webpage, id = the URL?

Comment: @Absinthe: Yes, in the case of `WebPage` (or also `Article`, if the page only contains this article) it makes sense to use the (canonical) document URL as ID. --- The fragments `#this` or `#i` are conventions that get used for the things described on the page (like organizations, persons etc.); see an [explanation for the homepage of an organization website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099116/1591669)